# How can I get the MAC/IP address of a packet device in pcap.net/SharpPcap?

Tags: c#, network-programming, pcap.net, sharppcap

I'm using the PacketDevice or LivePacketDevce in order to send and receive packets. I have 2 network interfaces that I have to use and I can't find an attribute of Packet Device that has it's MAC or IP address. It's a problem using the destination of incoming packets as I am relying on arp broadcasts.
Is there any way to get the IP or MAC addresss of a packet device in pcap.net or using SharpPacap? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICaptureDevice.MacAddress` should give you the adapter's mac address, so the `MacAddress` property of your live devices.

Answer (score 0):

In [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net), there's an extension method for this:

```
public static MacAddress GetMacAddress(this LivePacketDevice livePacketDevice)
```